# remote desktop to Fedora 20 with xrdp

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora

I was able to setup xrdp on my Fedora 13 machine and access it from my Windows 7 machine by follow the steps on the first post on this [thread](http://www.linux.org/threads/rdp-into-your-linux-desktop.8/)

It was simple and easy.

But when i try the same on my Fefora 20 machine, things are quite different. There is no error message but some new info like these:

**# chkconfig --levels 35 xrdp on**

**Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable xrdp.service'.**

**# service xrdp start**

**Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  xrdp.service**

and then I cannot remote it from my window machine.

I also did the following based on the last post of above threa:

**# yum -y install tigervnc-server**

Any configuration I should do to make xrdp works for me?

I was able to ping each other.

**EDIT:**

I can access the shared folder on my Windows machine from my Fedora 20. It seems the problem is on the Fedora side. how to know the service on linux is running? The "service --status-all" cannot give me useful information.

Comment: try this http://networkstatic.net/xrdp-an-easy-remote-desktop-setup-for-your-ubuntu-servers/

Comment: tried several times. Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have a the "PREFERRED=gnome" line in /etc/sysconfig/desktop

Even though this is no longer mentioned in the current RHEL/Fedora documentation, it's noted in older documents from redhat [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-sysconfig.html#s2-sysconfig-desktop) and seems to still work in F20.

There's also a [BZ](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=904248) about this which seems to not be getting attention.

*You can also set this to other window manager if you're using mate, xfce, etc*

I had to do this on F20 to get xrdp working properly with my mate instance.